Pass variable / data from pre-test to test in SQL Server Unit Test
How can I pass a variable from my pre-test to my test in a SQL Server Unit Test?



From reading the MSFT documentation, it seems like they didn't really solve this.  We can't directly pass variables/data between the pre-test & test.  They have a hard-coded known ID:

-- NOTE: Assumes that you inserted a Customer record with CustomerName='Fictitious Customer' in the pre-test script.

source

Using a global temp table, ##SomeTableName, is working but that seems brittle & if multiple people/jobs run against the same SQL server, it will produce inconsistent results.  This approach would seem to fall victim to the same approach from the MSFT documentation with using a hard-coded ID.

That is pretty annoying huh. To be honest I've found the database unit test framework pretty clunky and hard to work with. I only did a proof on concept but that was enough.

Unit testing T-SQL from C# doesn't really seem like unit testing. Have you seen tSQLt yet? If you like a GUI then Redgate also wrapped a commercial product, SQL Test, around it.
